# What function and where is $this->getPriceHtml() located?

Tags: magento

On the default product view page for magento where is "getPriceHtml" function located or what is being called here:

```
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

Several words are being displayed by this code such as "Price From:" with the price included afterwards.  This is for a configurable product.

Comment: `grep -srl 'n getPriceHtml' ./`

Comment: Note this code `getPriceHtml(...)` is not Locate friendly. In my case, `the Special Price:` never changes to the selected language.

Comment: "Special Price" is translated via the Attribute label and not via the Magento translate.csv / locale csv layer. Edit the attribute via "Manage Attributes" in the Magento backend, setting the label specifically for the specific store view. Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 76):

`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml()`

This method renders via `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`

a.k.a `The Worst Template In Magento®`

Comment: I want to upvote for Funny. Need the Slashdot options of Insightful, Funny, etc. Not that your answer isn't useful, but as your initial comment said, it should be trivial to find...

Comment: @benmarks:how the function getPriceHtml is connected with its rendering phtml file? i know price block renders by itself, but how it is connected with price.phtml

Comment: You could copy this file to your theme and rewrite it, which is what most themes do.

Answer (score 5):

benmark's answer comes down to this:

```
<?php echo Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Where `$_product` relates to the product object.

Comment: This will throw notices about calling this method statically.

Comment: Use @valir method to avoid notices

Comment: Instead of calling it statically do
`<?php
    $productBlock = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;
    echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
?>`

Comment: Since PHP 7 you can only call this by creating an instance, the static call in the answer above (and in many old templates) won't work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

```
    $productBlock = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product();

    $priceBlock = $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product, true);

    echo $priceBlock;
```